# Compatible Memory Upgrade for Toshiba Satellite Pro

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, ddr2

My old laptop is a Toshiba Satellite Pro L300 1Af with a maximum upgrade capability of 4 GB. Crucial's System Advisor couldn't recommend any compatible memory. There are two of these modules fitted at the moment:
[image]

[image]

I replaced them with two of the modules above. It's over a month since I ordered them, so I can't remember why I chose this type, maybe I looked at a YouTube video on upgrading this model of PC. Anyway they don't work, and the system doesn't attempt to boot. I presume the bus speed isn't compatible with them (Crucial says its 667 Mhz) or they're faulty. Both the new and old are PC2-6400. So my question is, is the module shown in the second photo the correct replacement type?

Edit: Took the modules out, slid them in and out a few times to "wipe" the contacts. Now the system boots ok and Crucial reports that it has 4GB installed. I'm running Windows 10 on this old machine and upgraded the HDD to an SSD. It works fine and isn't terribly slow, considering it's a 2008 model or thereabouts, although I had to remap several non-functioning keys with PowerToys. It's good enough as a backup laptop.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I've updated the post above to include a question.

Comment: Both of those modules are unbuffered, non-ECC, 800MHz DDR2 modules.  There is no reason those modules shouldn't work.

Comment: They are now after taking out and putting back in again. I was going to try some IPA on the contacts, but was a bit worried about rubbing and static. So, I just slid them in and out a few times before snapping the clips shut. That seemed to have wiped the contacts and made them work.

Comment: If it works, I'd say it's the "right" type. Did you attempt to inquire with Toshiba?

Comment: No, I've never had much luck getting their customer support to help. I find with any of these tech companies, they just spout general fault finding procedures. I've always had to solve my own technical problems using my own methods or asking questions on forums such as this.